# Не могу дорисовать кирпичную стену

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame

Помогите пожалуйста дорисовать кирпичную стену, дальше второй кладки у меня продвинуться не получилось.

**main.py**:

```
import pygame

w = 300
h = 200
pygame.init()
size = w, h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'))
n = 30
m = 0
q = 30
a = 30
p = 60
d = 0

while n <= 200:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), (0, n), (300, n), width=2)
    n += 30
    m += 1
    if m % 2 == 0:
        while p <= 300:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), (p, d), (p, d + 30), width=2)
            p += 60
    elif m % 2 != 0:
        while q <= 300:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), (q, a), (q, a + 30), width=2)
            q += 60

pygame.display.flip()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

w = 300
h = 180
size = w, h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'))

n = 30
m = 0
q = 30
a = 30
p = 60
d = 0

while n <= 200:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), 
        (0, n), (300, n), width=2)
    n += 30
    m += 1
    
    if m % 2:
        while q <= 300:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), 
                (q, a), (q, a + 30), width=2)
            q += 60 
    else:
        while p <= 300:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), 
                (p, d), (p, d + 30), width=2)
            p += 60
        d += 60
        p = 60
    q = 30
    a += 30
            
pygame.display.flip()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass
    
pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]